# Block Thread for other operation

Tags: java, synchronization

I have a case such that 5 threads exist in a project, let's say A,B,C,D and X.

Thread X is triggered periodically to invoke a `methodX()` and update an object.
I want A,B,C and D to all block while X is invoking a method `methodX()`;
otherwise A,B,C and D will continue without waiting on each other.
Let's say A,B,C and D are invoking same method, `methodCommon()`.

How can I implement such a case?  Using `synchronized` and reentrant locks will not be suitable for this case.

Comment: Use a [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have two basic options:

1. Wrap the work code in threads A-D (`methodCommon()` in your case) with a `try-catch` block that catches an `InterruptedException`. The `catch` block calls whatever method contains the work you want A-D to do when X is finished with `methodX()`.
2. Declare a *volatile*, *synchronized* variable that X will use to flag A-D, and that A-D need to check regularly to see whether they should do something special.

Each approach has tradeoffs. Approach 1 may cause A-D's data to be unstable (it depends on what they're specifically doing). Approach 2 may result in A-D doing a bit more work than you intend, or the response being slightly less than snappy, etc. (again, depends specifically on what these threads are doing).

Comment: I'm curious what you understood the question to be. Sounds to me like a simple read/write scenario. I don't see how either of your suggestions are relevant.

Comment: I could ask you the same question. How are you getting "read/write scenario" from a question that had no mention of reading or writing, other than what's implied by thread X updating an object?

Comment: I mean it in the sense that X is exclusive to A-D, which are not exclusive to each other. That's a classic read/write lock scenario, regardless of the actual operations in question.

Comment: It's not clear from the OP whether A-D and X are locking on any given shared objects; I only got that A-D had to keep working until X notified any / all of them to something else important. It's also not evident that A-D should block if they attempt to access an object they share with X.

Comment: @shmosel summized the question thanks.  X is exclusive to A-D, which are not exclusive to each other.

Answer (score 1):

`ReentrantReadWriteLock` solves your problem:

```
ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
Lock readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();
Lock writelock = readWriteLock.writeLock();
```

Use `readLock` in A, B, C, D and `writeLock` in X

Answer (score 0):

Use `wait` and `notifyAll`,  try something like this:

```
public class ThreadLetter extends Thread{

private Object trigger;

public ThreadLetter(Object trigger, String name){
this.trigger=trigger;
super(name);
}


@Override
public void run(){
synchronized(trigger){

try{
trigger.wait();

}catch(InterruptedException e){

}
//invoke whatever method needs to be invoked
}
}

}
```

**Thread X:**

```
public class ThreadX extends Thread{

private Object trigger;


public ThreadX(Object trigger){
this.trigger=trigger;
super("threadX");
}

@Override
public void run(){
synchronized(trigger){

try{
//invoke methodX

trigger.notifyAll();

}catch(InterruptedException e){

}

}
}

}
```

**Main class:**

```
Object trigger=new Object();

ThreadLetter A=new ThreadLetter(trigger,"A");
ThreadLetter B=new ThreadLetter(trigger,"B");
ThreadLetter C=new ThreadLetter(trigger,"C");
ThreadLetter D=new ThreadLetter(trigger,"D");

ThreadX X=new ThreadX(trigger);

X.start();

A.start();
B.start();
C.start();
D.start();
```

Comment: if ThreadX does not run, other threads are kept in WAITING status, this is not what I want